# How to create wordpress page that shows posts with specific tags?

Tags: pages, tags

Like the title says, what code would I use on a wordpress page so that it will only show posts that have a specific tag?

Answer (score 2):

I'm pretty sure I always read on here that `new WP_Query()` is recommended over `query_posts`.  Additionally you can use the [Transient API](http://codex.wordpress.org/Transients_API) to improve performance on additional queries.  Place this in whatever template where you'd like the list to display:

```
// Get any existing copy of our transient data
if ( false === ( $my_special_tag = get_transient( 'my_special_tag' ) ) ) {
    // It wasn't there, so regenerate the data and save the transient

   // params for our query
    $args = array(
        'tag' => 'foo'
       'posts_per_page'  => 5,
    );

    // The Query
    $my_special_tag = new WP_Query( $args );

    // store the transient
    set_transient( 'my_special_tag', $my_special_tag, 12 * HOUR_IN_SECONDS );

}

// Use the data like you would have normally...

// The Loop
if ( $my_special_tag ) :

    echo '<ul class="my-special-tag">';

    while ( $my_special_tag->have_posts() ) :
        $my_special_tag->the_post();
        echo '<li>' . get_the_title() . '</li>';
    endwhile;

    echo '</ul>';

else :

echo 'No posts found.';

endif;

/* Restore original Post Data
 * NB: Because we are using new WP_Query we aren't stomping on the
 * original $wp_query and it does not need to be reset.
*/
wp_reset_postdata();
```

And in your function.php you will need to clear out the transient when things are updated:

```
// Create a function to delete our transient when a post is saved or term is edited
function delete_my_special_tag_transient( $post_id ) {
    delete_transient( 'my_special_tag' );
}
add_action( 'save_post', 'delete_my_special_tag_transient' );
add_action( 'edit_term', 'delete_my_special_tag_transient' );
```

Answer (score 1):

Before the loop, use query_posts function

```
query_posts( 'tag=foo' );
```

This will returns all posts with the assigned tag.

```
<?php
// retrieve post with the tag of foo
query_posts( 'tag=foo' );
// the Loop
while (have_posts()) : the_post();
    the_content( 'Read the full post »' );
endwhile;
?>
```

You can also use it to return posts with multiple tags

```
query_posts( 'tag=foo,bike' );
```

For further parameters and reference, see
http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query#Parameters
http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/query_posts

Comment: Thanks! Also found this plugin as well: http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/list-category-posts/other_notes/

Comment: Whatever works, it's best to avoid using plugins if it can be done within the theme folder.  Cuts down on load time and server space.

Comment: That’s wrong, it doesn’t matter where the code comes from. If you store plugin code in a theme file you just cannot turn it off separately. Do as little as possible in a theme to make your life easier.